# is there a way to make Chrome Default Page Zoom Setting %80?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-mavericks

there are just %90, %75, and smaller values

%90 setting is too big and %75 setting is too small for me.

How can i set chrome default page zoom setting to %80?

[image]

edit:

chrome version : Version 31.0.1650.57
mac os x Version 10.9
screen resolution : 1920 x 1080

Comment: I have different zoom option to you, including an 83%... Either we're on different versions (10.0.648.151) or it's based upon the computers screen resolution and maybe the figures it gives are for better scaling

Comment: @DaveRook i am using chrome on mac osx mavericks in 1080p.